# Dynamic form additional fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have been using this below js fiddle to do what I need it to however I just need to give each addition a new id.. does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/nj4N4/7/

```
<span>Width: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small> X </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to console to see each `width` with id

```js
var room = 1;
function add_fields() {
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Room ' + room +':</div><div class="content"><span>Width: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[ id='+ room +']" value="" /><small>(ft)</small> X</span><span>Length: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" namae="length[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small></span></div>';
    
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
```

```css
div { padding:10px;}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />

       <div id="room_fileds">
           <div>
            <div class='label'>Room 1:</div>
            <div class="content">
                <span>Width: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[id=1]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small> X </span>
                <span>Length: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" namae="length[]" value="" /><small>(ft)</small></span>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The length[] and width[] will work just fine - you will get two arrays in the $_POST. You can then do something like:

```
foreach ($_POST['length'] as $key => $val) {
   echo "length: " . $_POST['length'][$key] . ", width: " . $_POST['width'][$key];
}
```

Alternatively if you'd like have them numbered, you can use the room number variable "room", numbering each of the fields like:

```
divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Room ' + room +':</div><div class="content">';
divtest.innerHTML += '<span>Width: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width_' + room +'" value="" /><small>(ft)</small> X</span>';
divtest.innerHTML += '<span>Length: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" namae="length_' + room +'" value="" /><small>(ft)</small></span>'
divtest.innerHTML += '</div>';
```

Comment: The 'room' variable which is supposed to increment doesn't seem to be adding to any variable's past 1? Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Please check the updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nj4N4/549/ and when I add rooms I see (in the source) fields named like: width_1, width_2, width_3.. is that what you wanted or do you need something else?

Comment: **Look at fiddle please:** http://jsfiddle.net/nj4N4/551/ We know that the incrementing is working as ingredient 1: textbox foodtype 2: textbox is being shown, therefor i can only assume the name is not accepting the `+room+` for some reason?

Comment: @AliceB1 it is working for "name" also - you can check it with the browser's developer tools checking the generated code: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="ingredient_2" value=""> or by posting the form generated in such way and listing the $_POST variables in PHP